# How to count the change_flag per month per id in my data frame

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data frame which is like this .

```
database
     id change_flag month_end
1  R018           0         0
2  K018           1         0
3  R018           1         1
4  K018           1         1
5  R018           0         1
6  K018           1         0
7  R018           1         1
8  R018           0         1
9  K018           1         1
10 R018           1         1
11 R018           1         0
12 R018           0         0
13 R018           1         1
14 R018           0         0
15 K018           1         0
```

Here change_flag 1 indicates that a change happened and month_end 1 means its a month end and 0 means its not a month end .

Now for both the ids I would like to count the change that happened every month.
However I am not able to figure out how to achieve this .Thanks

```
     id change_flag month_end    changePerMonth
 1: R018           0         0    NA
 2: R018           1         1    1
 3: R018           0         1    0
 4: R018           1         1    1
 5: R018           0         1    0
 6: R018           1         1    1
 7: R018           1         0    NA
 8: R018           0         0    NA
 9: R018           1         1    2
10: R018           0         0    NA
11: K018           1         0    NA
12: K018           1         1    2
13: K018           1         0    NA
14: K018           1         1    2
15: K018           1         0    NA
```

Is there a way to achieve this with data.table as well

Comment: I would suggest making a column in you dataframe of all NA values, The easiest way to do the counting that you've suggested would be with a while loop

Comment: What is the logic behind the `changePerMonth` column? - I can't figure it out.

Comment: @thelatemail the data here is in sequence ,i.e , every row in the data frame denotes a certain day of a month and month_end flag =1 denotes that point as a month end  .Now I want to calculate 
the total no of changes happened in one month ,which would be 
the total no of change happened between two month ends.for example 
look at rows 6:9,6 th row denotes a month end and 9th row denotes a month end now in between there are two changes for the month which is denoted by the monthend flag=1 at row 9

Answer (score 3):

Here is an attempt:

```
database$chperm <- NA
database$chperm[database$month_end==1] <- with(
  database,
  ave(
    change_flag,
    list(id,rev(cumsum(rev(month_end)))),
    FUN=sum
  )
)[database$month_end==1]
```

In a data.table world I would try:

```
database[, chpermdt := sum(change_flag), by=list(id,rev(cumsum(rev(month_end))))]
database[month_end != 1, chpermdt := NA]
```

Both give:

```
#      id change_flag month_end changePerMonth chperm
#1:  R018           0         0             NA     NA
#2:  R018           1         1              1      1
#3:  R018           0         1              0      0
#4:  R018           1         1              1      1
#5:  R018           0         1              0      0
#6:  R018           1         1              1      1
#7:  R018           1         0             NA     NA
#8:  R018           0         0             NA     NA
#9:  R018           1         1              2      2
#10: R018           0         0             NA     NA
#11: K018           1         0             NA     NA
#12: K018           1         1              2      2
#13: K018           1         0             NA     NA
#14: K018           1         1              2      2
#15: K018           1         0             NA     NA
```

Comment: is there a way to do it in data.table way . I have thought a lot about it but have not figured it out